# How valid are Paul Steinhardt's criticism of inflationary theory?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

I recently read about [Paul Steinhardt's criticism of inflationary theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Steinhardt#The_multiverse), which can be boiled down to "if inflation predicts everything (c.f. the multiverse), then it also predicts nothing, and if it predicts nothing, it's not a scientific theory". This seems like a pretty obvious statement to me, and one that's important to address for the theory since it's an objection at the fundamental level.

However the theory also seems very much alive, with lots of people continuing to work on it. It seems people don't care about / don't give credit to this objection at all.

Why? The obvious answer is that there's something about Paul Steinhardt's criticism that is invalid or omitted. The obvious "something" that is omitted would be that inflation has indeed made predictions that were later verified. However [this website](http://physics.princeton.edu/~cosmo/sciam/index.html#facts) lists all those predictions and shows that at various points his critics have written papers claiming other results were possible, which seems like a very powerful answer.

Why don't people care about / don't give credit to this objection at all?

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, it's just for straight Q&A.  Your question seems to be primarily opinion based and not a straight question with a straight answer and is inviting a discussion (hence off topic, IMO).  You might try the chat rooms if you want to see if there's an interest in discussion.

Comment: have you read any accounts of the history of the inflationary model?

Comment: @StephenG not much to discuss from my point of view - I've said everything I can think of, so I'm only really looking for an answer.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I know bits and pieces of it, although I'm no historian of science. Why?

Comment: having it explained to you would answer most if not all of your questions.

Comment: @nielsnielsen are you saying Paul Steinhardt's objections are based on emotion not science? They don't look like emotional arguments to me. Can you write an answer?

Comment: No, I am not. Did somebody say I was?  What I am saying is this: If you were familiar with what's in the model, how it was developed, how it evolved mathematically over time, what things it successfully predicts and so on, it would put you in a much better position to assess the validity of Steinhardt's claims. Have a look at Hogan's book "The Little Book Of The Big Bang" for a start.

Comment: @Allure That's simply how model building works. There are many ways to build complicated models that can achieve pretty much anything you want to achieve. However, you shouldn't forget that all _simple_ inflationary models (which receive over 95% of the attention) make many shared, concrete predictions that have been well verified. People have tried more complicated stuff just to see what was out there, and that's not a failure of inflation.

Comment: @Allure I mean, you can say the same for any theory. For example, the Standard Model predicts 3 species of neutrinos, but people have considered what would happen if there were more than 3. Obviously, these models make different predictions, namely they predict more than 3 neutrinos. This does not make the Standard Model itself any less valid.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I sort of assumed that if the history matters then the objection cannot be scientific (science doesn't depend on who developed the theory / how it came into being, right?). Sorry!

Comment: @knzhou I'd say elaborate on that into an answer, but the question is closed =/

Answer (score 2):

Even a theory that predicts that nearly any observation is possible can be refuted in a probabilistic sense if we observe something that it assigns microscopic probability to. And many useful theories allow nearly anything, yet remain scientific.

It is worth noting that this applies to quantum mechanics: QM allows nearly any observation of (say) a particle position, but clearly makes nontrivial and useful predictions about how the probability varies depending on experimental conditions.

Multiverse theories vary in how much variance they predict. Inflation models allow for domains with different settings of many physical constants but not different fundamental rules. One can argue that some probabilities for these values can be estimated, or get into arguments about whether anthropic arguments are valid. String theory seems to allow even more fundamental vacua and here the extreme flexibility seems to be a serious problem since we do not know how to get it to predict anything about our universe. Hardcore Tegmark Level IV multiverses where everything that can consistently exist does exist in a real sense are even worse: they are so vast that it is not clear probabilities can be well defined.

This is already somewhat a problem in inflation models since how to define the relevant "measure" becomes subtle. This looks like Steinhardt's beef with the theory, but other physicists and mathematicians disagree on this. Like much of theoretical physics it is contested in terms of philosophy of science too; this is simply the messy state of the cutting edge. Just because somebody thinks they have a killer argument doesn't mean it actually convinces others.